# font size in chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, scaling, chemfig

I am using `chemfig` scaling and want to increase the font size, but not any other parameter of the molecule. So a MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackge{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\definesubmol{R1}{--[:150]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::60]}
\definesubmol{R2}{--[:30]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::-60]}
\definesubmol{R3}{-[,0.6]}
\chemfig[][scale=0.7]{([:-18]N*5((!{R1})-(!{R3})=\chemabove{N}{\quad\scriptstyle\oplus}([:342]!{R2})-=-))}

\end{document}
```

Can I increase the font size minimally without changing the rest of the molecule?

Comment: You have two possibilities: redefine `\printatom` to use a larger font or set the bond length (via `\setatomsep`) to use a fixed length instead of a font-size dependent one.

Comment: how would I redefine \printatom to use, say, \Large font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise, the first or the second optional arguments of `\chemfig` do not take the option `font=\Large` (which is a `tikz` option for node font), contrary to what manual states. Here are the two methods mentioned by  cgnieder along with a scalebox version (very hacky).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}
%% ugly method and not advisable
\definesubmol{R1}{--[:150]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::60]}
\definesubmol{R2}{--[:30]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::-60]}
\definesubmol{R3}{-[,0.6]}
\chemfig[][scale=0.7]{([:-18]\vphantom{N}\scalebox{1.2}%
{\smash{N}}*5((!{R1})-(!{R3})=\chemabove[0.8ex]{\vphantom{N}\scalebox{1.2}%
{\smash{N}}}{\quad\scriptstyle\oplus}([:342]!{R2})-=-))}

%% change printatom
\renewcommand * \printatom[1]{\Large\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}

\definesubmol{R1}{--[:150]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::60]}
\definesubmol{R2}{--[:30]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::-60]}
\definesubmol{R3}{-[,0.6]}
\chemfig[][scale=0.7]{([:-18]{N}*5((!{R1})-(!{R3})=\chemabove{N}{\quad\scriptstyle\oplus}([:342]!{R2})-=-))}
\renewcommand * \printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}   %% resetting for the example


%% fix a static bond length
\setatomsep{5mm}
\definesubmol{R1}{--[:150]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::60]}
\definesubmol{R2}{--[:30]-[::-60]-[::60]-[::-60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::+60]-[::-60]}
\definesubmol{R3}{-[,0.6]}
\chemfig[][]{([:-18]{N}*5((!{R1})-(!{R3})=\chemabove{N}{\quad\scriptstyle\oplus}([:342]!{R2})-=-))}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use the second version and encapsulate big molecules like this in the two renewcommand statements so that it's applied locally. Thank you very much!

Comment: You *can* use `font=\large` if you prevent it from expansion in the wrong moment, e.g. by loading `etoolbox` and adding `\robustify\large` to the preamble

Comment: @cgnieder: Yes, I found that out soon after posting the answer (and it was not smooth). But I felt that it is again hacky, hence didn't add it. Thanks for noting though. :-)

Comment: IMHO it isn't (but that's just an opinion...). None of 2e's macros are engine protected since it predates eTeX. I imagine that the corresponding macros in a future LaTeX3 probably will be...

Answer (score 1):

Changing the atom separation to 2em and subsequent scaling of the figure works fine in my case.

```
\setatomsep{2em}\chemfig[][scale=2.0]{<figure-description>}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.